# Convert PEM string into X509 cert using node js without using node-forge

Tags: javascript, node.js, x509certificate, node-forge

How can I convert PEM string into X509 certificate & extract Subject Alternative Name from it without using any node module like "node-forge". I am receiving following PEM string:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

delete -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----
use "@peculiar/x509" mycertificate is the text of the .pem without --begin - / - end-- const cert = new x509.X509Certificate (mycertificate);